# VS 2012 - Can't add MySQL.Data libraries to my WP7 C# project

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, mysql-connector

I have the problem described in question title.

I doesn't understand for what exactly reason(s) Nuget can't add libraries of MySQL.Data framework to my project (Silverlight v4.0 / C# target Windows Phone 7.1) in Visual Studio 2012 Express (on Windows 8 Pro x64). I tried also to add manually the .dll files downloading them by official MySQL site (6.5 and newer versions), but unsuccessfully.

It says that the package doesn't contain some references to assemblies or data files compatible with the (MySQL.Data) framework.

Any ideas how to risolve this problem?

P.S.: it give me the same error when I try to install Nuget.Core package, I don't know if it's a symptom of a corrupt Nuget manager...

Comment: Since Silverlight/Windows Phone has a very limited set of .NET framework features, chances are high that MySQL.Data depends on features that are unavailable for that platform. Same applies to NuGet.Core.

Comment: But i don't understand why only this package can't instal...I used other packages for my actual project without any problem

Comment: If you look in the packages directory, do these packages come with a SL4 folder? Each package must explicitly support the framework you've selected, otherwise it won't install. System.Data generally not supported by Windows Phone. Not even the SqlClient. This is by design. You need to expose your database by providing a webservice to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL.Data package depends on the System.Data library to create a connection directly to your database. Direct database connections are not supported by the Windows Phone libraries, since it would require your phone to connect to your databases and establish a stateful connection. These types of connections are brittle and costly to maintain.

When you browse your `packages\**library**\Lib` folder you'll see a binary for each supported platform. For example the `HTMLAgilityPack` includes a `sl4-windowsphone71`, and is thus supported. The `MySQL.Data` does not, and as such is not supported:
[image: Difference between support of framework versions]

Instead you'll need to expose a webservice (XML or JSON for example) which can be consumed by your Windows Phone app in a stateless fashion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can understand and I will follow your method!